Single Query to return result from multiple tables in mysql
I have the following tables
Table: tblperson



id
name




1
John


2
William


3
Adam



Table: tbloccupation



id
personid(fk)
occupation




1
1
Lawyer


2
1
Social worker


3
2
Doctor


4
2
Social worker


5
3
Teacher


6
3
Accountant



frontend application has single text box to search by name or occupation.
i would like to create single select query to search in both tables.
ex: if someone search john, it should return one single row
|name | occupation         |
|-----|--------------------|
|john |Lawer, social worker|

ex: if someone search for social worker, it should return two rows
| name    | occupation            |
|---------|-----------------------|
| john    | Lawer, social worker  |
| William | Doctor, Social worker |


PROPOSED QUERY
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT A.name,GROUP_CONCAT(B.occupation) occupations
FROM tbloccupation B INNER JOIN tblperson A
ON A.id = B.personid GROUP BY A.name) AA
WHERE occupations LIKE '%Social Worker%';

YOUR SAMPLE DATA
MySQL lalitmohan> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS lalitmohan;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.03 sec)

MySQL (none)> CREATE DATABASE lalitmohan;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MySQL (none)> USE lalitmohan
Database changed
MySQL lalitmohan> CREATE TABLE tblperson
    -> (id int not null auto_increment,
    -> name varchar(20),
    -> primary key (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

MySQL lalitmohan> INSERT INTO tblperson (name) VALUES ('John');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

MySQL lalitmohan> INSERT INTO tblperson (name) VALUES ('William');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MySQL lalitmohan> INSERT INTO tblperson (name) VALUES ('Adam');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

MySQL lalitmohan> CREATE TABLE tbloccupation
    -> (id int not null auto_increment,
    -> personid int not null,
    -> occupation varchar(20),
    -> primary key (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

MySQL lalitmohan> INSERT INTO tbloccupation (personid,occupation) VALUES
    -> (1,'Lawyer'),
    -> (1,'Social Worker'),
    -> (2,'Doctor'),
    -> (2,'Social Worker'),
    -> (3,'Teacher'),
    -> (3,'Accountant');
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MySQL lalitmohan> SELECT * FROM tblperson;
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | John    |
|  2 | William |
|  3 | Adam    |
+----+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL lalitmohan> SELECT * FROM tbloccupation;
+----+----------+---------------+
| id | personid | occupation    |
+----+----------+---------------+
|  1 |        1 | Lawyer        |
|  2 |        1 | Social Worker |
|  3 |        2 | Doctor        |
|  4 |        2 | Social Worker |
|  5 |        3 | Teacher       |
|  6 |        3 | Accountant    |
+----+----------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL lalitmohan>

PROPOSED QUERY TESTED
MySQL lalitmohan> SELECT * FROM
    -> (SELECT A.name,GROUP_CONCAT(B.occupation) occupations
    -> FROM tbloccupation B INNER JOIN tblperson A
    -> ON A.id = B.personid GROUP BY A.name) AA
    -> WHERE occupations LIKE '%Social Worker%';
+---------+----------------------+
| name    | occupations          |
+---------+----------------------+
| John    | Lawyer,Social Worker |
| William | Social Worker,Doctor |
+---------+----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL lalitmohan>


A combination of join and group by and group_concat will go bed you your wanted result.
Gropu_concat has also a order by so you can order as you want it
In your where clause you enter the wanted  criteria
If you collation is case sensitive you can always convert the search text to a ci collation see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-search-case-insensitive-in-a-column-using-like-wildcard-in-mysql/
 SELECT p.name
   , GROUP_CONCAT(o.occupation) as occupation
FROM tblperson p JOIN tbloccopation o ON p.id = o.personid
wHERE p.name like 'John' OR o.occupation like 'social worker'
GROUP BY p.name



frontend application has single text box to search by name or
occupation. i would like to create single select query to search in
both tables.

This query can return the results as expected:
SELECT 
    pe.name, GROUP_CONCAT(oc.occupation SEPARATOR ', ') occupations 
FROM 
    tblperson pe, tbloccupation oc
WHERE 
    pe.id = oc.personid
    AND 
    pe.id IN (  
      SELECT id FROM tblperson WHERE name = @input
      UNION
      SELECT personid FROM tbloccupation WHERE occupation LIKE @input
    )
GROUP BY 
    pe.name;


ex: if someone search john, it should return one single row

When the value of @input is 'john' the result is (e.g., in mysql client use SET @input = 'john'):
+------+-----------------------+
| name | occupations           |
+------+-----------------------+
| john | Lawyer, Social worker |
+------+-----------------------+


ex: if someone search for social worker, it should return two rows

And, when the value of @input is 'social worker':
+------+-----------------------+
| name | occupations           |
+------+-----------------------+
| jane | Social worker, Doctor |
| john | Lawyer, Social worker |
+------+-----------------------+

